# Moment of Inertia for a hollow cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

This question may be to rudimentary.

I have found 2 formulas for calculating the inertia of a hollow cylinder.  Which is correct or are they used for different circumstances?  They seem to be used interchangably which simply imputing the same variables proves to be untrue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first equation is for a hollow cylinder that has a thickness, hence the $r_i$ and $r_o$ (inner and outer radii respectively). The second equation is for a thin hollow cylinder, for which the thickness is negligible, so $r_i$ can be assumed to equal $r_o$.

As expected, setting $r = r_i = r_o$ and substituting into the first equation yields the second equation.